# Excel VBA Macro to split long row into many of equal length

Tags: excel, vba

I am currently working on a problem where I have an Excel Spreadsheet that I would like to use a VBA macro on.  Each of the following 3 rows are consecutive.

```
Name of Data                                                            
abc A1  B2  B4  C4  E2  F43 d4  V8  f9  k11 j20 …           x

cde A2  B3  B12 C6  E9  F34 d6  V4  f13 k111    j209    …           x

efg A3  B5  B7  C8  E11 F68 d19 V12 f91 k114    j2014   …           x
…       






Desired                                                         
abc A1  B2  B4  C4  E2  F43 d4  V8                          
abc f9  k11 j20 …                                           
cde A2  B3  B12 C6  E9  F34 d6  V4                          
cde f13 k111    j209    …                                           
efg A3  B5  B7  C8  E11 F68 d19 V12                         
efg f91 k114    j2014   …
```

I have the data name for each row and some rows can be hundreds of entries long spanning hundreds columns. *So what I would like to do would be make my row length stop at  8 columns wide. I would hope that the macro can check through each row to see if the length is greater than 8, insert a row with the same data name and paste the next 8 columns, subtract it from the total columns and paste the next row, until it has reached the end of the first long row, and continue checking through all the rows. In essense, it saves a whole lot of time from counting up 8 columns wide, cut and pasting it in an inserted row below, preserving all other data.* I'm new to this, so macro or VBA help is much appreciated.

Thanks, 
John

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/) The expectation here is that you show us the code that is not working for you and we help you.

Comment: Is each piece of data in its own column, or are they really long strings stored in one column?

Comment: Hi Scott, I lost the exact code I was working on but I was trying to manipulate each individually which contained more than 8 rows wide.

Comment: try the macro recorder while you do it manually, then `Loop` through each row and use `Column Counts` to test. Post where you get stuck and we can help.

Comment: @ Scott Holtzman, lost exact code I was working on but I was trying to manipulate each individually which contained more than 8 rows wide.                                                                  The formula I was trying to use to include in my code was the =INDEX (("row specified) -1 *8 - (columns)-1).  This is pseudocode as well because I lost the exact code I was working with. I was hoping to use this in a macro and then add onto the functionality by checking against each row in the spreadsheet. 


And yes @Sam, each piece of data is in its own column. Does that make things easier?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The below macro will do exactly as you ask. It has some assumptions that I'll leave to you to fix, such as

- Data is in sheet 1
- Name column is always **A**, all data columns start from **B**
- Everything starts in cell **A1**

This macro will run through every row and, for those rows with more than 9 data elements, it will create a new row and populate it with the previous rows `Name` and the remaining data rows. It will continue doing this until there is less than or equal to 8 data elements per row.

Since you have MANY rows you say, it would be a good idea to **turn off screen updating**, like so `Application.ScreenUpdating = False` before the for loop and turn it back on after the for loop.

```
Public Sub SplitRows()

Dim rowRange As Variant
Dim colCount As Integer
Dim lastColumn As Long
Dim rowCount As Integer
rowCount = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

Dim i As Integer
i = 1
Do While (i < rowCount)
    lastColumn = Sheet1.Cells(i, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    colCount = Sheet1.UsedRange.Columns.Count
    rowRange = Range(Cells(i, 2), Cells(i, colCount))
    'if the row has more than 9 values (name column + 8 data columns)
    If Not lastColumn <= 8 Then
        Dim x As Integer
        'from column 2 (B, aka first data column) to last column
        For x = 2 To colCount - 1
           'if data is not empty AND x mod 8 is 1 (meaning 8 goes into x enough times to have a remainder of 1)
            If Not IsEmpty(rowRange(1, x - 1)) And (x Mod 8) = 1 Then
                Cells(i, 1).Offset(1).EntireRow.Insert  'insert new row below current row
                rowCount = rowCount + 1                 'update row count because we added a row
                Sheet1.Cells(i + 1, 1).Value = Sheet1.Cells(i, 1).Value     'set first column name
                Dim colsLeft As Integer
                For colsLeft = x To colCount - 1
                    'take data value from col 9 to end and populate newly created row
                    Sheet1.Cells(i + 1, colsLeft - 7).Value = rowRange(1, colsLeft)
                    Sheet1.Cells(i, colsLeft + 1).Value = ""    'set data value from col 9 on and set to empty
                Next
            Exit For    'exit loop, weve done all we need to and must now check the newly populated row
            End If
        Next
    End If
    i = i + 1
Loop
End Sub
```

Here is a before and after of the results:

**BEFORE**

[image: Before Macro:]
**AFTER**
[image: After macro:]

Comment: Hi Sam, this looks like it would work except, it only inserts the rows for me and then crashes. Any chance it has to do with the format of the data in the cells?

Comment: That could be. Could you provide a sample of the data?

Comment: Hi @Sam, Sometimes the values in the cells are separated by a dash "-"

Comment: It would be very nice if you could provide some sample data from your workbook that would allow me to update the code appropriately.

Comment: Glad you were able to figure it out! Best of luck with the rest of your project.

Comment: Hi @Sam, I am having difficulty with this macro again. I have ran it on your test data to see the desired outcome. I also ran it once on my data and it worked perfectly. However, I am having trouble to replicate those results. In my data columns, sometimes the data is separated by dashes and that appears to throw it off as well as in the names in column A may be separated by _ or have + or "-". This also seems to occur with characters "(" and ")".  It seems to insert the row, but not perform the cut and paste operation. Any ideas Sam?

Comment: I'm sorry to hear you're having issues. As you know, this was built with many assumptions and on a very limited set of data. I asked for a sample of your data to get an idea of what different cases there may be, but I was never provided that information. I can't help much more without understanding the true requirements. You should get a list of concrete requirements written down so YOU know what the module should do/ how it should do it BEFORE asking questions here. SO members can only help if they understand the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Argh, I tried somewhat along this lines, but I have to go to work. Maybe it is helpful as a starting point.

```
Public Sub Test()
Dim mastercell As Range
Set mastercell = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Cells(1, 1)
Dim masterValue As String
masterValue = mastercell.Value

If GetCount(masterValue) > 8 Then
    Dim tempvalue As String
    tempvalue = masterValue
    Dim Rowcount As Integer
    Dim ColCount As Integer
    Rowcount = mastercell.Row
    ColCount = mastercell.Column + 1
    Do While GetCount(tempvalue) > 8
        Dim WriteValue As String
        WriteValue = GetFirstEight(tempvalue)
        ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Cells(Rowcount, ColCount).Value = WriteValue
        ColCount = ColCount + 1
        tempvalue = Replace(tempvalue, WriteValue, 0, 1)

    Loop
End If

End Sub

Private Function GetCount(str As String) As Integer
Dim Splitter As String
Splitter = " "
Dim SplitArray As Variant
 SplitArray = Split(str)
GetCount = UBound(SplitArray)
End Function

Private Function GetFirstEight(str As String) As String
Dim i As Integer
Dim NewString As String
Dim SplitArray() As String
SplitArray = Split(str)
For i = 0 To 7
    NewString = NewString & SplitArray(i) & " "
Next
GetFirstEight = NewString
End Function
```

Comment: Thank you Christian I will this a shot!