# split one row into 2 rows in excel

Tags: excel, vba

I have a requirement to split a single row into 2 rows depending on the value of one of the flags in the row. The structure is as below:-

```
Exp_id  Flag_1 guar_percent
aaaa    Y   20
bbbb    N   0
cccc    Y   100
dddd    Y   90
```

Among all the above rows, all the rows which have Flag_1 as 'Y' and guar_percent >0, <100 are to be split to below :- (I can populate the guar_percent columns later after the split has happened)

```
Exp_id  Flag_1 guar_percent
aaaa_G  Y   100
aaaa_NG Y   0
dddd_G  Y   100
dddd_NG Y   0
```

Thanks

Comment: don't do this in excel. do it wherever  the excel is being generated...

Comment: Maybe he has output data in excel "report" format that no longer exists in the original source.

Comment: The second table will be in a different tab/workbook. There are millions of records received, out of which half a million will be with flag_1 as 'Y'. Any suggestions to automate this process. We donot have control on the data in the source file, the first table in this case.

Comment: Why do companies insist on storing their data in Excel format, using network access permissions as a pseudo-database????

Comment: Start with this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14245727/excel-vba-macro-to-split-long-row-into-many-of-equal-length?rq=1

Comment: Used:- If UCase$(Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(iRow,2).Value)="Y" Then Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & CStr(iRow+1)).Select            
Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & iRow).Copy Destination:=Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1) Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Value=Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & iRow).Value+"_G" Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & iRow).Copy Destination:=Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1) Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Value=Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & iRow).Value+"_NG"

Answer (score 0):

If you setup your input range into an array and process that it should be a relatively painless exercise.  The following code is thoroughly commented but if it doesn't make sense, let me know.

```
Option Explicit

Sub SortData()
    Dim vInData As Variant, vOutData As Variant
    Dim ii As Long, lCounter As Long
    Dim wkOut As Worksheet

    'Read in your data, you could set this as a function and pass it any range
    vInData = ActiveSheet.Range("A1:C8").Value2

    'Double up the output array just in case every record is valid, we can redim after processing
    'Also not we've transposed the array because you can only redim preserve the second bound
    ReDim vOutData(LBound(vInData, 2) To UBound(vInData, 2), LBound(vInData, 1) To 2 * UBound(vInData, 1))

    'Loop through the input
    For ii = LBound(vInData, 1) To UBound(vInData, 1)
        'Check for the yes flag first
        If vInData(ii, 2) = "Y" Then
            'Then check the percentage bounds
            If vInData(ii, 3) > 0 And vInData(ii, 3) < 100 Then
                'Increase the counter by two since we're adding two lines.
                lCounter = lCounter + 2
                vOutData(1, lCounter - 1) = vInData(ii, 1) & "_G"
                vOutData(2, lCounter - 1) = "Y"
                vOutData(3, lCounter - 1) = 100
                vOutData(1, lCounter) = vInData(ii, 1) & "_NG"
                vOutData(2, lCounter) = "Y"
                vOutData(3, lCounter) = 0
            End If
        End If
    Next ii

    'Now we have all the outputs redim the array to remove empty elements
    ReDim Preserve vOutData(LBound(vOutData, 1) To UBound(vOutData, 1), LBound(vOutData, 2) To lCounter)

    'I've just dumped the output onto a fresh sheet, you can set the output array to any range on any worksheet you like
    Set wkOut = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Add
    With wkOut
        .Name = "Output"
        .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(UBound(vOutData, 2), UBound(vOutData, 1))).Value2 = Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose(vOutData)
    End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what I did and it worked. Any suggestions to optimize it are welcome. thanks all.

```
Sub SplitRec()
    Dim getRow As Long
    Dim LR As Long
    Dim RowCount As Integer

    For getRow = 1 To Worksheets("Sheet1").UsedRange.Rows.Count Step 1

         If (Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(getRow, 111).Value) > 0 And (Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(getRow, 111).Value) < 1 Then

            Worksheets("Sheet1").Rows(getRow).Copy Worksheets("Sheet2").Rows(Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(Worksheets("Sheet2").Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row + 1)
            Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Value = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & getRow).Value + "_G"

            Worksheets("Sheet1").Rows(getRow).Copy Worksheets("Sheet2").Rows(Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(Worksheets("Sheet2").Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row + 1)
            Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Value = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & getRow).Value + "_NG"

        Else
            RowCount = RowCount + 1

            Worksheets("Sheet1").Rows(getRow).Copy Worksheets("Sheet2").Rows(Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(Worksheets("Sheet2").Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row + 1)
            Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Value = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & getRow).Value

        End If
    Next

End Sub
```